# Detect mouseclick in unused area of the datagridview below the last row

Tags: datagridview, mouseevent

I have a dgv control which covers most of a form.  If the dgv contains only a few rows of data, most of the dgv area below the few rows is a no-mans-land.  I would like to detect if the user mouse-clicks in this no-mans-land. Possible?

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing that is to use the [`DataGridView.HitTest`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.hittest(v=vs.110).aspx) function. It returns a [`HitTestInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.hittestinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) that provides information about where the mouse clic occured.

Here is an example :

```
private void dataGridView1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
          DataGridView.HitTestInfo hit = dataGridView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
          if (hit.Type == DataGridViewHitTestType.None)
          {
               // Do your stuff
          }
    }
}
```